# ajax call with rails not updating content

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

i'm trying to get the content of a div to change when i click a link. i can see from the console that the partial and the js is being rendered, however, my html does not update

in index.html:

```
<div id="test">this is supposed to change</div>
 ...

<%= link_to 'planner', test_path(:budget => "b2", :size => "g2", :age => "a1", :activity => "l2", :tourist => "t2", :city => "boston"), :method => :get, :remote => true, :id => "linkto" %>
```

in my planner_controller:

```
    respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.js {render :layout => false}
```

in update.js.erb:

```
$("#test").update(" <%= escape_javascript(render('load')) %>")
```

_load.html file:

```
<p> test </p>
```

could the error be that i'm just testing the code, and not actually doing anything with the results of the query?

Comment: Are you calling the update action from the link in index page? I think you have issues in your link path. Check it and provide some clear information. If you are trying to call update action then it must have some id associated with it and the method should be 'put'. I would recommend to create a custom action for such tasks.

Answer (score 0):

You are updating an element with an id of `test` but you don't have that element anywhere on your page.

Comment: forgot to add, but i have "    <div id="test">this is supposed to change</div>    " at the top of my page

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#test").update(" <%= escape_javascript(render :parial => "load") %>")
```

Try this

Answer (score 0):

You can use replaceWith() in place of update()

```
$("#test").replaceWith(" <%= escape_javascript(render('load')) %>")
```